# Process finished with exit code 11 | Error during malloc

Tags: c, malloc

Trying to understand memory allocation in C. Facing issue while trying to create two arrays using pointer to integers. Kindly have a look at the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int *a;
    int *b;

    for (int i = 0; i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter value \n");
        a[i]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        b[i]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
    }
    for (int i =0;i<4;i++)
    {
      printf("%d = %x\n  ",a[i],&a[i]);

    }
    for (int i =0;i<4;i++)
    {
     printf("%d = %x\n  ",b[i],&b[i]);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am working with C11 on CLion. Facing below error on runtime. Can someone please explain what is wrong with this code ?

```
Enter value 

Process finished with exit code 11
```

[image: b is being shown as NULL during debugging]

"b is being shown NULL during debugging"

UPDATE:
Tried on another IDE, where "a" itself is not being allocated any memory. It directly gives me segmentation fault.

UPDATE 2:
Changing:

```
int *a;
int *b;
```

to

```
int *a = NULL;
int *b = NULL;
```

at least stops how this code is behaving. It gives me segmentation fault as soon as I try to allocate memory to a[i] (Which is wrong, now I get).

Comment: `a[i]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));`: `a` doesn't point anywhere. It is not initialized. You want `a =(int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);`. But also other issues.

Comment: You should alloc memory for pointers as well.

Comment: You need to go back to whatever book or tutorial you're following or reading, and take a close look on what it tells you about pointers and dynamic allocation. What you're doing is wrong on many levels.

Comment: If I remove "b" completely from the above code, it allocates memory for array "a" for 4 integers and prints the entered or scanned values. Issue only comes once I try to allocate memory for another array.

Comment: You should never cast `malloc`.

Answer (score 3):

While the code do allocate memory for four `int` values, it does not work as you expect.

If we start from the beginning:

```
int *a;
```

This defines (and declares) a variable `a` which is a pointer to an `int`. You do not initialize it, which means its value is *indeterminate* (and will seem totally random). Dereferencing this (with e.g. `a[i]`) leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Then

```
for (int i = 0; i<4;i++)
{
    a[i]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    ...
}
```

If you properly initialized `a` it would already point to memory for four `int` values. You could see `a` as an array, and you don't need to allocate each member of the array separately. This is indicated by the types, `a[i]` is of type `int`, not `int *`.

The "best" solution is to not use pointers or dynamic allocation at all, and instead use plain arrays:

```
int a[4];

for (int i = 0; i<4;i++)
{
    printf("Enter value \n");
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);  // No allocation needed, a[i] already exists
}
```

If you *must* use pointers and dynamic allocation, then allocate memory enough for four `int` elements, and make `a` point to the first byte:

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);

for (int i = 0; i<4;i++)
{
    printf("Enter value \n");
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);  // No allocation needed, a[i] already exists
}
```

There are a few other problems as well, but start with these.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe there must be some other way to implement it. I want to allocate memory only till user wants to quit the program. "4" integers I only took for the example. For ex. user is typing and memory should be allocated until he enters "Q".

Comment: @Manoj Then read about [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion in your code:

- you do not allocate the arrays for `a` and `b` to point to. `a` and `b` are uninitialized, dereferencing them has undefined behavior. `a` shows as `NULL` in the debugger, but the C Standard does not guarantee that. `a` could have any value, including trap representations that would cause undefined behavior just by reading it.
- you store a pointer to `int` into `a[i]`: the compiler should issue a diagnostic about the type mismatch. It is unfortunate that this not be a fatal error IMHO, but ignoring compiler warnings is always a bad idea.
- the return value of `malloc()` is cast as `(int *)`. This is necessary in C++, but considered bad style in C.
- the third argument in `printf("%d = %x\n", a[i], &a[i]);` is inconsistent with the conversion specifier: if you want to print the value in hex, use `printf("%d = %x\n", a[i], a[i]);`, if you want to print the address, use the `%p` conversion specifier: `printf("%d at %p\n", a[i], (void*)&a[i]);`

To play with `malloc()`, you should just allocate the `int` arrays, check for allocation success and free the memory after use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int *a;
    int *b;

    a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * 4);
    b = malloc(sizeof(*b) * 4);
    if (a == NULL || b == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("Enter 2 values\n");
        if (scanf("%d%d", &a[i], &b[i]) != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("  %d = %x\n", a[i], a[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("  %d = %x\n", b[i], b[i]);
    }
    free(a);
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As soon as I marked int *a = NULL; It stops working. Moreover, without NULL, if I print the "printf("%p\n",*(&a+1)-*(&a));" It prints the size that is accessible for "a" i.e. 0xffffe000462fd622.  Thanks.!!

Comment: @Manoj: with `int *a = NULL;`, your code has undefined behavior of the first kind: easy to spot because you are dereferencing the null pointer directly, which causes a segmentation fault on most current operating systems. Run with a debugger and the offending code will be easy to spot. With `int *a;`, the code has undefined behavior of the third kind: what actually happens depends on many factors, including alien influence... It may not crash immediately, but who knows what side effects may have been triggered... Harder to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these lines, because you need to create memory so that you can assign values later:

```
  int **a = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * 4);
  int **b = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * 4);
```

You are assigning pointer values to elements of `a`. Therefore `a` should be pointer to pointer.
Complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{

  int **a = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * 4);
  int **b = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * 4);

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      printf ("Enter value \n");
      a[i] = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int));
      b[i] = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int));
      scanf ("%d", &a[i]);
      scanf ("%d", &b[i]);
    }
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      printf ("%d = %x\n  ", a[i], &a[i]);

    }
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      printf ("%d = %x\n  ", b[i], &b[i]);

    }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter value 
4
5
Enter value 
1
2
Enter value 
6
7
Enter value 
8
9
4 = 165d010
  1 = 165d018
  6 = 165d020
  8 = 165d028
  5 = 165d040
  2 = 165d048
  7 = 165d050
  9 = 165d058
```

Comment: In the last program, `scanf("%d", &a[i]);` should be replaced with `scanf("%d", a[i]);` and `printf("%d = %x\n  ", a[i], &a[i]);` with `printf("%d = %x\n  ", a[i][0], a[i][0]);`. As you say, memory allocation for this is completely unnecessary and leads to confusing code.

Comment: I don't see the need to allocate an "array" of *pointers*?